При компиляции программы, после добавления на форму объекта DBGrid, возникает системная ошибка. (Code: 5 Отказано в доступе)
Делаю простенькое приложение в Delphi 7 для работы с базой данных (задание в университете). На одной из форм нужно добавить DBGrid для выводы данных из базы данных, но после добавления на форму объекта DBGrid, при компиляции появляется окно с текстом: "System Error. Code: 5. Отказано в доступе". Если удалить DBGrid, компилируется нормально.
Ещё несколько дней назад этой проблемы не было, и все работало. Также попробовал с нуля создать это приложение и выяснил, что ошибка появляется именно на этом моменте.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Т.е. просто кидаете на форму DBGrid, никакие свойства у него не трогаете, никаких действий с ним не производите -- и ошибка? Пробовали Delphi с правами администратора запускать?
